# How do I modify the gnuplottex.sty file to write a hash character (#) into the plot file?

Tags: symbols, gnuplot

I have problems with adapting a .sty file for my needs. The problems are caused by the special meaning of the hash character # in tex (and also my ineptitude). To the problem:

An unmodified "gnuplottex.sty" file from the **gnuplottex** package reads in part like this:

```
\def\figname{\jobname-gnuplottex-fig\thefignum}

\def\gnuplotverbatimwrite#1{%
    \def\BeforeStream
    {\message{Opening gnuplot stream #1}%
        \immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string !/usr/bin/gnuplot -p}
        \immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string set terminal \gnuplotterminal \gnuplotterminaloptions}
\immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string set output '\figname.\gnuplottexextension{\gnuplotterminal}'}
    }
```

The **package writes a file** that might be named `test-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot`. The quoted lines in the .sty file in particular are responsible for the following content of the of this file:

```
set terminal tikz
set output 'test-gnuplottex-fig1.tex'
```

I **would like the file to read**:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
set terminal tikz
set output 'test-gnuplottex-fig1.tex'
```

But the hash character (#) poses a problem: When I edit the quoted part of `gnuplottex.sty` to read:

```
\def\figname{\jobname-gnuplottex-fig\thefignum}

\def\gnuplotverbatimwrite#1{%
    \def\BeforeStream
    {\message{Opening gnuplot stream #1}%
        \immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string #!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p}
        \immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string set terminal \gnuplotterminal \gnuplotterminaloptions}
\immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string set output '\figname.\gnuplottexextension{\gnuplotterminal}'}
    }
```

It produces the error:

> l.89 ...  \immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string #!     /usr/bin/gnuplot -p} ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \BeforeStream."

If I escape the hash like in `\immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string \#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p}` the file has an extra backslash in there instead of really escaping the hash:

```
 \#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
 set terminal tikz
 set output 'test-gnuplottex-fig1.tex'
```

In this context how do I escape the hash character in the right way for the line to read `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify the package file `gnuplottex.sty`. Rather, redefine the relevant command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\makeatletter
\edef\gnuplot@hashmark{\string#}
\def\gnuplotverbatimwrite#1{%
  \def\BeforeStream
    {\message{Opening gnuplot stream #1}%
     \immediate\write\verbatim@out{\gnuplot@hashmark!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p}
     \immediate\write\verbatim@out{set terminal \gnuplotterminal \gnuplotterminaloptions}
     \immediate\write\verbatim@out{set output '\figname.\gnuplottexextension{\gnuplotterminal}'}
    }
    \@bsphack
    \immediate\openout \verbatim@out #1
    \BeforeStream%
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
    \catcode`\^^M\active
    \def\verbatim@processline{%
        \immediate\write\verbatim@out
        {\the\verbatim@line}}%
    \verbatim@start}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}
abc
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

This results in writing

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
set terminal latex
set output 'gplote-gnuplottex-fig1.tex'
abc
```

Note that I removed a couple of useless `\string` commands from the definition.

Since `\write` expands tokens, when it finds `\gnuplot@hashmark` it will expand it to a "safe" version of `#`.

You should also try asking for a bug fix.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this as soon as I have a chance to. Concerning the bug fix: None is needed, I just want gnuplottex to generate gnuplot files that can stand alone as well.